# Problem with WMS/WMTS Layer Image Quality in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, image, resolution, aerial-photography

I have been using an aerial provided by the state. I add the layer as a WMS/WMTS. Typically the quality is on-par with the resolution depicted in the online hosted mapping program (GeoWeb). However, after use the image suddenly turns pixelated. There is another person in my office using the same version of QGIS (most recent update) and the aerial as a WMS/WMTS with no resolution issues. Once the pixelation begins it does not seem to go away, even if I remove and reload the layer, and the resolution issues are carried through when printed or made a PDF. What could be causing the resolution issues and what could be done to restore it back to the original quality?

Please let me know if additional information is needed, I am just beginning to work with QGIS and may have left information out due to inexperience.

A screenshot of my resolution issues and a link to the original aerial are attached. Please note the "zig-zag" appearance of the building outlines. They usually start as more crisp, particularly at this scale.

http://geodata.state.nj.us/imagerywms/Natural2015?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the native CRS of the WMS layer? Is your project in a different CRS?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the WMS/WMTS layer?

Comment: The image and my work is in NAD83/New Jersey (ft US) EPSG: 3424 and the link is below.

[link] (https://img.nj.gov/imagerywms/Natural2015?)

Comment: I believe I figured it out. It was a silly simple problem, I had rotated the aerial. Once set back to 0 the image was no longer distorted.